# Баг в канвасе при отрисовке второго круга возникает линия

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Есть канвас, на нем сетка, которую можно перерисовывать по нажатию на кнопки.

Канвас отслеживает клики пользователя, округляет их координаты до координат пересечения сетки и ставит там точку. Можно ставить любое количество точек, все будет нормально, но при попытке поставить вторую точку на место уже существующей происходит баг, заключающийся в появлении некой линии на пол канваса(небольшая поправка: только при 2 последовательных отрисовках кружка на одном месте, если создать круг 1 и круг 2, а потом нажать на 1 ничего не произойдет, но если еще раз нажать на первый то линия отрисуется).

Помогите её убрать. При этом всем все линии идут в одну точку.

Скрин на котором все точки в одном экземпляре:
[image: все точки в 1 экземпляре]

Скрин на котором все точки в нескольких экземплярах:
[image: Все точки в 2 экземплярах]

Код:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var degree = Math.PI / 180;

var draw = {
  ctx: canvas.getContext('2d'),

  grid: true,
  area: true,
  border: true,


  pattern() {
    this.ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 660, 660);
    this.ctx.closePath();

    if (this.grid)
      this.Grid();

    if (this.area)
      this.Area();

    if (this.border)
      this.Border();
  },

  draw() {
    this.pattern();
  },

  Grid() {
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = '#CCC';
    this.ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    for (let x = 30; x < 660; x += 30) {

      //varctical
      this.ctx.beginPath();
      this.ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
      this.ctx.lineTo(x, 660);
      this.ctx.closePath();
      this.ctx.stroke();

      //horixontal
      this.ctx.beginPath();
      this.ctx.moveTo(0, x);
      this.ctx.lineTo(660, x);
      this.ctx.closePath();
      this.ctx.stroke();
    }
  },

  Area() {
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    this.ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    this.ctx.strokeRect(30, 30, 600, 600);
    this.ctx.closePath();
  },

  Border() {
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    this.ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    this.ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, 660, 660);
    this.ctx.closePath();
  },

  change(name) {
    if (name == 'grid')
      this.grid = !this.grid;

    if (name == 'area')
      this.area = !this.area;

    if (name == 'border')
      this.border = !this.border;
  },

  circle(x, y) {
    this.ctx.fillStyle = '#f47e46';
    this.ctx.arc(x, y, 10, degree * 0, degree * 360);
    this.ctx.fill();
    this.ctx.closePath();
  }
};

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
  let x = e.pageX - e.target.offsetLeft,
    y = e.pageY - e.target.offsetTop,

    x_pos = Math.round(x / 30) * 30,
    y_pos = Math.round(y / 30) * 30;

  console.log([x_pos, y_pos]);
  draw.circle(x_pos, y_pos);

});

gridb.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  draw.change('grid');
  draw.draw();
});

areab.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  draw.change('area');
  draw.draw();
});

borderb.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  draw.change('border');
  draw.draw();
});

draw.draw();
```

```css
.button {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="660" height="660"></canvas>
<input class="button" value="Grid" id="gridb" type="button">
<input class="button" value="Point area" id="areab" type="button">
<input class="button" value="Border" id="borderb" type="button">
```

Comment: `this.ctx.closePath();` есть а `this.ctx.beginPath();` для него отсутствует

Comment: @Grundy ок спасибо :) Нужен ли тогда this.ctx.beginPath(); перед отрисовкой fillRect() and strokeRect()? И сделайте тогда ответ чтобы можно было отметить верным

Comment: вообще он нужен там, где path рисуется